Job always updates in Terraform
I'm deploying a list of AWS Glue jobs (water-name) using a variable in list(object) (water-name-configs) format. When Terraforms checks the deployment plan it is always getting differences even though the variable has not been changed. I'm suspecting it is implementing dynamic variables by default.
My implementation code is the following:
resource "aws_glue_job" "water-name" {
  count       = length(var.funny-name-configs)
  name        = "water-name-${var.water-name-configs[count.index].table_name}"
  description = "water-name-${var.water-name-configs[count.index].table_name}"

Can you check where I'm going wrong?
I did try to add dependencies to the job.
depends_on = [var.water_name]
I expect to be able to avoid to redo all my terrafrom code, declaring a variable for each element of the array water-name.

You need to show your terraform plan output which will include the reason Terraform thinks the resource needs to be updated. You should probably also include the var.water-name-configs variable definition as well.

it could be a bug in the provider, ... what I do not like on your code is you have one variable for the count and another for the name, that code smells funny

Did you change the order of the elements in the variable funny-name-configs?

I tested your code making up the content of the variables and the rest of the aws_glue_job:
variable "funny-name-configs" {
  default = ["a", "b"]
}

variable "water-name-configs" {
  default = [{table_name:"a"},{table_name:"b"}]
}

resource "aws_glue_job" "water-name" {
  count       = length(var.funny-name-configs)
  name        = "water-name-${var.water-name-configs[count.index].table_name}"
  description = "water-name-${var.water-name-configs[count.index].table_name}"

  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::621655500000:role/aws-service-role/support/AX"
  command {
    script_location = "s3://foo/example.py"
  }
}

If I run multiple applies on that we can see the first time it creates the resources, and the following applies do not see any changes
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

aws_glue_job.water-name[0]: Creating...
aws_glue_job.water-name[1]: Creating...
aws_glue_job.water-name[1]: Creation complete after 0s [id=water-name-b]
aws_glue_job.water-name[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=water-name-a]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.


heldersepu@bat: terraform apply
aws_glue_job.water-name[1]: Refreshing state... [id=water-name-b]
aws_glue_job.water-name[0]: Refreshing state... [id=water-name-a]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.


heldersepu@bat: terraform apply
aws_glue_job.water-name[0]: Refreshing state... [id=water-name-a]
aws_glue_job.water-name[1]: Refreshing state... [id=water-name-b]

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

There must be something else you did not provide in your example
